# Remove small lines detected by OpenCV HoughLines

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to detect lines from noisy image and as a result I get too many lines. I need to iterate through lines multiple times and this is just too slow with so many lines, I am only interested in lines that are long enough.

My code to detect lines is as follows:

```
// Edge detection
int lowThreshold = 35;
Canny(greyMat, dst, lowThreshold, lowThreshold * 3, 3);
cv::blur(dst, dst, cv::Size(2,2));
// Standard Hough Line Transform
std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines; // will hold the results of the detection
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, rho_resolution, 150, 0, 0 ); // runs the actual detection
```

My source image is [image: source image]

And the resulting image from Canny is [image: result image from Canny]

HoughLines will detect 100 lines, I am only interested in the long ones in the middle that form a rectangle. How can I remove the short lines? If I increase Canny threshold some lines I need are not detected.

Comment: You can use `HoughLinesP`. The 6th argument is the minimum line length to be detected

Comment: If you want to get the red rectangle, you can try `findContours` and `boundingRect/minAreaRect` .

Comment: @Silencer That is what I want but sometimes edges are blurry with colour bleed as I try to detect TV screen. First tried detecting rectangle directly with findContours and that just does not work, now trying to work out rectangle from lines.

Comment: @superg you should do some preprocessing such as `GaussBlur` or `morphologyEx` to reduce the noise. And you didn't post your original image, os it's hard to decide which method to use.

Comment: @Silencer Actually the first one is "original" image. It is cumulative diff data from captured video. Any motion on TV screen basically makes pixels red eventually. OpenCV erode function may work in removing thin lines before Canny, will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

blur the image to reduce the noise or little details in frame, it worked for me.

```
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 25    
smoothed = cv2.filter2D(frame, -1, kernel)

gray=cv2.cvtColor(smoothed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edge=cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 150)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edge, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

General the method is to blur the image, which is done to make sure the noise is suppressed in the image leaving back only the actual edges of the objects to be detected.

The type of method used is subjective to the image. You can play around with Median or/and Gaussian Filter before extracting edges and check if you find any improvement.